# Why $\int f(t) dt = \int f(t) \frac{dt}{dx} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

I've stumbled upon this in another question, and cannot really grasp the core of this equality:

$$\int f(t) dt = \int f(t) \frac{dt}{dx} dx$$

Maybe it's partly due to the confusing Leibniz notation which looks like fractions (?) but it's not. So what happens here?

Is it some fundamental theorem of calculus? Or integration by substitution?

Any reference to a "standard" textbook that explains it in detail is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it [...] integration by substitution?

Yes, it is. This is exactly the statement of integration by substitution, neither more nor less. To be more explicit, the right-hand side could be written as $$\int f(t(x))\frac{dt}{dx} dx$$

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, $t$ (you might also write it $t(x)$) is a function of $x$. Let $F$ represent the left-hand integral, that is, a function such that $F'(t(x)) = f(t(x))$. The claim is that $F(t(x))$ is actually an antiderivative (with respect to $x$) of the function $f(t(x)) t'(x)$. But this is simply the chain rule for differentiation!

Comment: Thanks! So $t'(x)$ is simply $\frac{dt}{dx}$. But why do we switch the variable for integration, from $dt$ to $dx$?

Comment: The utility of this equality (which, as Arthur states, is integration by substitution) comes in when you're dealing with a variable transform. If f is originally defined in terms of t, but t is implicitly a function of x, then it makes sense that we would want to compare antiderivatives wrt t to antiderivatives wrt x, because one (usually the left one) might be easier than the other.